# How I can update old realex payments code to latest 3ds v2?

Tags: global, payment

my old code is using xml and json is like this need to update this to latest 3D Secure v2.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://epage.payandshop.com/epage-remote.cgi");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "payandshop.com php version 0.9");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // this line makes it work under https 
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: not exactly but I have updated my code with HPP embeded payment form which is working fine